# Mobile Safari 10 IndexedDB Blobs

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, indexeddb

IndexedDB in Safari 10 supports blobs now. This works fine on desktop, however mobile Safari on iOS 10 throws an error:

```
UnknownError
```

and sometimes in combination:

```
TransactionInactiveError (DOM IDBDatabase Exception): Failed to store record in an IDBObjectStore:
The transaction is inactive or finished.
```

The code (shortened):

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB,
    READ_WRITE = IDBTransaction && IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE ? IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE : 'readwrite',
    storeName = 'files',
    db;

init: function() {
    var request = indexedDB.open('mydb');
    request.onerror = ...;
    request.onupgradeneeded = function() {
        db = request.result;
        db.createObjectStore(storeName);
    };
    request.onsuccess = function() {
        db = request.result;
    };
},

save: function(id, data) {
    var put = function(data) {
            var objectStore = db.transaction([storeName], READ_WRITE).objectStore(storeName),
                request = objectStore.put(data, id);

            request.onerror = ...;
            request.onsuccess = ...;
        };

    // not all IndexedDB implementations support storing blobs, only detection is try-catch
    try {
        put(data);
    } catch(err) {
        if (data instanceof Blob) {
            Helpers.blobToDataURL(data, put);
        }
    }
}
```

On Mobile Safari 10 `.put()` doesn't throw like before, only later in the async error-callback.

Base64 strings work fine.

Bug in Mobile Safari or do I have to change code?

Test Case: http://fiddle.jshell.net/j7wh60vo/7/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ran across the same problem. Chrome 54 and Safari 10 work fine on desktop, but on Mobile Safari I kept getting the `Unknown` error when trying to store a Blob into IndexedDB. I can confirm that this really is just an issue with Blobs on Mobile Safari, and not some misuse of the API.

Fortunately, ArrayBuffers work fine. So I instead downloaded the images like:

```
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
```

Then saved them into IndexedDB as ArrayBuffers, and converted them to Blobs after pulling them out to get a url:

```
putRequest = objectStore.put(arrayBuffer, id);
putRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
  objectStore.get(id).onsuccess = function(event) {
    var blob = new Blob([event.target.result], { type: 'image/jpeg'});
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  };
};
```

I'd rather not have to convert ArrayBuffers to Blobs like this as I assume there is a performance penalty. But it works.

Comment: Works very well, tnx! Base64 would be the other option but can blow up a file and I doubt if that would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

That error looks to me like you have to change the code. That error does not indicate an issue with blobs. That error indicates you have a problem somewhere in how you call functions. To better answer your question, you need to post more of the surrounding code. Specifically, display the parts of the code where you create the transaction and where you create requests on the transaction.

Edit: first, remove the window.indexedDB stuff. Second, do not use 'db' in the way you are using it, because that will not work, the db may be closed by the time save is called.

```
function save(id, data) {
  var openRequest = indexedDB.open(...);
  openRequest.onerror = console;
  openRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
    var db = openRequest.result;
    // Open the transaction
    var tx = db.transaction(storeName, 'readwrite');
    var store = tx.objectStore(storeName);
    // Immediately use the transaction
    try {
      var putRequest = tx.put(data, id);
      putRequest.onerror = console;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Edit2: Additional notes:

Prefixes have been removed, just use indexedDB, not mozIndexedDB or webkitIndexedDB etc

Transaction mode constants have been removed, use either 'readonly' or 'readwrite', or nothing (defaults to readonly)

I am somewhat confused how you are calling `request = transaction.put`. As far as I am aware, there is no method IDBTransaction.prototype.put as shown in the spec https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#idbtransaction. I am confused as to why the Mozilla docs show an example with transaction.put. Inspecting the prototype of IDBTransaction in Chrome 55 does not show a put method.

There is IDBObjectStore.prototype.put. Your code should not be working at all, on any platform, as it is currently written. So if it did ever work, I am surprised. You should only be using something like `var store = transaction.objectStore('store'); store.put(obj);` where you call put on the object store.

Comment: Sorry, just realized there is an answer due to lack of notification by SO. Code and question are updated.

Comment: transaction.put was a typo, the Mozilla docs had/have confusing naming, it's actually called on the objectStore (question edited)

Comment: Interesting that opening the db globally was wrong. It worked on all browsers so far and for 1+ years in production - except for Mobile Safari 10. Is it safe to open the db with every save call when there are potentially 5-10 concurrent saves?

Comment: It is actually more safe to open the db every call than it is to open it once. You can also try closing the db after every call using db.close(), but make sure you do it after and not before or you get a similar error. The reason it probably worked so often is related to async javascript, sometimes a global variable lives on to later uses of it. In fact alot of the time. But this is kind of a cheat, and can lead to problems exactly like what you are experiencing

Comment: Yes, I'm holding onto the open db object in a private static for the app's lifetime.

Comment: Changed the code, but doesn't change anything. Seems there really is an issue with blobs in Mobile Safari 10. The above error could be a side effect of the blob problem. Maybe related to the blob itself, which is created from new Blob(ArrayBuffer). MimeType and size are available on the blob.

Comment: The initial error is unknown (the actual error message from Safari). I'll force Mobile Safari back to base64 in the meantime.

Comment: A tx becomes inactive if no requests done immediately. Again you need to show more code.

Comment: Here's a test case, but I can't run it on iOS due to "SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): IDBFactory.open() called in an invalid security context": http://fiddle.jshell.net/j7wh60vo/7/

Comment: I can confirm the test case successfully saves a string in Mobile Safari.

Comment: The test case looks great. Is that your code? If not, are you doing something like starting a transaction, then fetching, then calling put? Because that would be a reason for a transaction to be inactive. Notice how in the test code it does the fetch prior to starting the transaction.

Comment: The test case is very similar to what I'm doing. The issue is not the transaction, it's blobs in Mobile Safari. The test case confirms that Mobile Safari saves strings but not blobs. I never have idle transactions. Btw, https://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js/ holds onto open connections globally, too.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem in all mobile browsers: iOS: Safari, FF, Chrome / Android: Chrome, FF, Edge. The code from Josh couldn't solve the problem. The only solution (workaround) seems to be the one from Augustin Bralley.